# Shared_ptr seems to work on copy, not on original object

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

I got 2 classes that represent Player and I want to keep in one of them pointer to another one.

So inside my `view::Player` I create pointer to `logic::Player`

```
    namespace view {
    class Player {
        std::shared_ptr<logic::Player> m_player;
        //logic::Player* m_player;
    public:
        void create(logic::Player& player) {
            m_player = std::make_shared<logic::Player>(player);
            //m_player = &player;
        }
    };
}
```

`view::Player` is created in `view::GameState` and simply initialised like this
`m_playerOneView.create(m_game.getActivePlayer());`

`m_game` is `logic::Game` object

`logic::Game` has `std::vector<logic::Player>`, and public method that returns active one

```
logic::Player& logic::Game::getActivePlayer() {
    return m_players[m_activePlayer];
}
```

And finnaly

```
namespace logic {
    class Player {
        std::string m_name;
        int position;
    };
}
```

Now I need original object of `logic::Player` pointed by `std::shared_ptr` in my `view::Player` class. I could simply do that by changing that to raw pointer and it works then (2 commented lines do what I want to achieve basicly). But when I try to do this on `std::shared_ptr`, I seem to work on copy of `logic::Player`, because when I update his position for example, it changes everywhere in the game but not in `view::Player`. How to do that using `std::shared_ptr` then?

Comment: `make_shared` makes a shared pointer to a *new* object. If you want a shared pointer to an existing object, you don't use `make_shared`.

Comment: So basicly, If this object is created outside my `view::Player` class, I should use raw pointer?

Comment: ...wait, why are you trying to create a `shared_ptr` to an element of a vector, anyway? `shared_ptr` is a reference-counting mechanism; it's not the type to use for a pointer to an object someone else owns.

Comment: Well yeah, since I'v learned about smart pointers I want to use them everywhere I can. Guess I can't use them in that case.

Comment: Also, taking a pointer into a vector is inherently dangerous if the vector is ever resized.

Comment: @Emdzej93 `shared_ptr` is a shared ownership pointer that requires special care to not screw up with.   `unique_ptr` is a unique ownership pointer that is harder to screw up.  Avoid persistant pointers between systems.